# Blog images not showing on homepage

Tags: posts, images, homepage, blog

Forgive me as I am new to this. 
The Blog is a separate page while the menu has 'news'. The pages are set in the screenshot but still doesn't show the blog images in the news section of the home page. [image]

I am having a bit of difficulty trying to get the blog images displayed on the home page. It used to show but disappeared on it's own. Any help or ideas? The blog page is the News page.

[image]

Comment: Can you please update here with code so I can help you.

Comment: Check to see if the images are throwing an error or are hidden for another reason. Try regenerating media. If that doesn't fix it, we'll need some code to see what's going on.

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to this. The Blog is a separate page while the menu has 'news'.